# Component vs MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, architecture, blazor, web-component, blazor-webassembly

I am working with Blazor currently, specifically Blazor WebAssembly. This is my first time really getting into web development and into an architecture and in this case it's component architecture. My experience with MVC is little-to-none, although I have made some small projects with Django in the past. I see that one of the powerful aspects of Blazor is the use of components which can increase development time and improve product quality. Components such as `<EditForm>`, `<InputText>`, `<DataAnnotationsValidator/>`, `<ValidationSummary />` are re-useable components which may allow for faster development as they can be used anywhere, context-free. I am curious to know how these components found in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components` actually provide a faster workflow compared to other architectures such as MVC. For example, why is having access to a single component such as `<DataAnnotationsValidator />` to validate data better/quicker? In MVC do you have to manually code checks for each data?

Answer (score 0):

In the case of components provided by microsoft, they're likely the same functionality provided in the other frameworks like MVC. There are things like the validation system in MVC, though I think in Blazor it's a bit more compact and does a bit more stuff for you like you don't have to include extra @ValidationMessage components for each form item like in MVC.

I think the idea that Components improve the things you've mentioned is not only that Microsoft provide a few, but that you can now create your own reusable components much easier than you could in MVC. You can also easily package them separately from a single project and import them into many others.

Using component based frameworks has its own design philosophy which you can read about